# how can i declare a variable or function globally as we declare in Objective C Macros

Tags: ios, swift

```
I want to make some functions and variables globally so that i can access those function and variables from any where



class:GlobalClass{
 let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
}
```

i am using a global class but every time when i want to use function i have to initialize the GlobalClass like:

```
GlobalClass().appDelegate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this by create a new file of name GlobalClass and import UIKit and Foundation in that class

and put your variable and function directly in this file like:-

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

let appDelegate  = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
let scree_width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

func status()->Bool{
  return true
}
```

you can access the variables and funnctions of this file any where like this:-

```
appDelegate
status()
```